# How to check mysql hashed password with salt

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using a tutorial to setup a mail server (its already working), and I want to also use the users table to login on the website.

The sql that the tutorial uses to create an account is:

```
INSERT INTO 'mailserver'.'virtual_users'
('id', 'domain_id', 'password' , 'email')
VALUES ('1', '1', 
ENCRYPT('PASSWORD', CONCAT('$6$', SUBSTRING(SHA(RAND()), -16))),
'email1@mysite.com');
```

The way I see it,

**ENCRYPT('PASSWORD', CONCAT('$6$', SUBSTRING(SHA(RAND()), -16)))**

Creates a salted hash, right? the thing is that the salt looks to be a random not stored value.

**How am I supposed to compare it with the password provided by the user?**

Postfix has no problem in doing it, since it works, so I have to be missing something

Comment: The ENCRYPT function will output a "salted" string prefixed with the salt itself, so feeding it back the encrypted password will re-supply the original salt.

Comment: @MarkBaker oh, i had no idea. Can you set a select example that validates to this in a proper answer? That way I can give you the full answer for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ENCRYPT function will output a "salted" string prefixed with the salt itself, so feeding it back the encrypted password will re-supply the original salt.

When you need to compare a password in the database with one that a user has entered, use a query like this

```
SELECT * FROM `mailserver`.`virtual_users`
 WHERE `email` = '<the email address entered by the user>'
   AND `password` = ENCRYPT('<the password entered by the user>', `password`);
```